# MIPS ascending buble sort to descending

Tags: mips

I'm a beginner at MIPS and hope somebody can answer this for me. Here is my MIPS code for sorting an array in ascending order:

```
.data
    nums: .word 10
    elems: .word 23, 42, 54, 10, 56, 78, 15, 43, 21, 87
    space: .asciiz " "
end: .asciiz "The end."
.text
        la $s0, elems
        lw $t4, nums
reset:  li $t0, 0 #offset
        li $t5, 0 #count up to nums
loop:   add $s1, $s0, $t0
        lw $s3, ($s1)
        addi $t1, $t0, 4
        add $s2, $s0, $t1
        lw $s4, ($s2)
        bgt $s3, $s4, swap
next:   addi $t5, $t5, 1
        addi $t0, $t0, 4
        beqz $t4, exit
        beq $t5, $t4, nummin
        j loop
nummin: subi $t4, $t4, 1
        j reset
swap:   sw $s3, ($s2)
        sw $s4, ($s1)
        j next
exit:   li $t0, 0
        li $t1, 0
loop2:  li $v0, 1
        add $t2, $s0, $t1
        lw $a0, ($t2)
        syscall
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, space
        syscall
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        addi $t1, $t1, 4
        beq $t0, 10, done
        j loop2
done:   li $v0, 4
        la $a0, end
        syscall
```

The code works and I got the output I want:

```
10 15 21 23 42 43 54 56 78 87 The end.
```

But when I try to turn it into a descending sort by switching $s3 and $s4 in **bgt $s3, $s4, swap** I get this output:

```
1750335520
87
78
56
54
43
42
23
21
15
```

Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going one step too far in the inner loop. Before you increment and leave that loop, $t5 = 9, and then $s1 will point at the last element and $s2 at the one after that. Then you will get a foreign value (1750335520) bubbling up to the top. Since it happened to be so large, sorting ascending worked.